# webview freeze in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, html, android-webview

i have an application in that i am loading webview in activity with url
also there is drawer 
and this is freeze in android 4.4.2 
, thats working fine in android 5.0 and 6.0 onward

as per android monitor log in freeze case is below
, thats log is repeat on every swype or touch

- I/View: Touch down dispatch to android.webkit.WebView{42841ec0 
  VFED..C. .F...... 0,0-480,666 #7f100075 app:id/web_view}, event = 
  MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=248.48233, 
  y[0]=327.48773, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, 
  metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, 
  eventTime=20907060, downTime=20907060, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }

  - D/VelocityTracker: Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (Permission denied)
  - D/VelocityTracker: tpd read x fail: Bad file number
  - D/VelocityTracker: tpd read y fail: Bad file number
  - I/View: Touch up dispatch to android.webkit.WebView{42841ec0 VFED..C. 
    .F...... 0,0-480,666 #7f100075 app:id/web_view}, event = MotionEvent { 
    action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=248.48233, y[0]=327.48773, 
    toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, 
    edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=20907129, 
    downTime=20907060, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }

and i set webview property like

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

and i set webclient

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
```

@Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback)
            {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
           }
            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg) {
            }
            //openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg,
                                        String acceptType,
                                        String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
             onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }
            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            }
        });   // End setWebChromeClient

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            Log.i("finished", url);
        }
    });
```

and here is my xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".LandingActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/bottom_option"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"></ListView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#454545" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navdrawer2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"></ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <include layout="@layout/listview_bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Even after refresh webview is still not work need help

Comment: Have you any solution?

Comment: not yet, i have still thats issue open for my devlopment

Comment: I was using Xwalk, switched to android webview and this problem occured

Answer (score 0):

Gradle with 3.0.0 and above and compileSdkVersion 26 above cause this problem...

My solution is not exact solution but it solve the problem...
switch app gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

switch module gradle to

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
```

change all other api to max 25 will solve frezee problem.. Until Main Solution comes it is worth to change these things!

Seems "Kotlin" is not as expected... Cause More work for CPU